# How to use Background Pages in Chrome to play a video stream?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to learn the Chrome Extension API, and I want to make a popup Twitch.TV or youtube video stream that is in a popup window that continues playing even after the popup window is closed. The user can then open the popup window again to see the video at its current point. Here's the code I have so far (popupbackground.js):

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var view = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup(view);

    });
```

is the javascript portion - as soon as the popup loads it searches for the background page and sets the popup to it. Here's the background page (popup.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>

    <div id="hello"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/utDHcbiOfKY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

as you can see it's a fixed iframe right now - I want to change that in future but I want to make sure it's working first with a single video before I go for multiple ones. Here's the page that I have set up as a dummy to run the javascript (randompage.html):

```
<html>

   <script src="popupbackground.js"></script>

</html>
```

and here's the manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "One-click Kittens",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a browser action with kittens.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "https://secure.flickr.com/",
    "contentSettings", 
    "background"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "randompage.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to think about background pages as if they were only js code.  The actual background page is only a container for the code, you shouldn't render anything on that page, user won't be able to see it.

On the other hand, popup pages are "short living".  They close when the user click outside, and destroy itself like any page on a tab when the user navigate off. Your video will close, its stream will close too.

I can't see a way to do what you want, but it doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically display a background page as a div, like hoverzoom does? That way the stream can always be running, but when the user switches tabs and clicks the button you can tell the background page to display again without restarting the video